# Rails how to count columns that are not blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller I have:

```
def sedomain 
 country_codes = %w[ dk se com net org info ]
@domains = { }
 country_codes.each do |cc|
    @domains[cc.to_sym] = { :navn => ".#{cc}" }
  end
render :layout => 'page'
end
```

dk se com net org info are columns in my domains table.

I want to count how many that are not blank

I have tried something like this:

```
def sedomain 
 country_codes = %w[ dk se com net org info ]
@domains = { }
 country_codes.each do |cc|
    @domains[cc.to_sym] = { :navn => ".#{cc}", :count => Domain.#{cc}.count }
  end
render :layout => 'page'
end
```

But I get a nomethod error.

Comment: Is it :count => Domain.#{cc}.count or :count => Domain."#{cc}".count ?

Comment: Is it Domain.#{cc}.count

Comment: # indicates comments.As the answer from tadman It will be :count => Domain.send(cc).count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Domain.count(cc)
```

or

```
Domain.count(cc, :conditions => ["`#{cc}` IN NOT NULL OR `#{cc}` != ''"])
```

Comment: This is working fine.  Is it better than Domain.where(:"#{cc.gsub('.', '')}".not_eq => nil).count ?

Answer (score 7):

You really need to get a book on Ruby because this is pretty straightforward. `#{...}` is an interpolator useful for *strings and strings only*. Outside of that specific context, `#` is usually interpreted as a comment and renders the remainder of the line invalid. A proper syntax-highlighting editor will reveal this, and even StackOverflow's code highlighter works this way.

What you need is `send`, as in `Domain.send(cc).count`.

Comment: I get a no method error: undefined method `dk' for #<Class:0x753c258>. I did figure out to use :count => Domain.where(:"#{cc.gsub('.', '')}".not_eq => nil).count which do work.

Comment: Using `send` is a Contrived Complexity codesmell in most cases.

Comment: It's a functional solution and with properly vetted input it works well, but it should be one of the first things you refactor when you look at cleaning up the implementation. Wrapping it in a method that handles validation and delegation in a single, testable interface is a superior solution. In this case it is a literal translation of what was intended with `#{...}`.